# :not CSS selector doesn't work for class in span within a span

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm having a pretty straight-forward problem here.  The :not selector is not working for a class (spaceless) attributed to a span within another span.  However, when spaceless class is in its parent div, the :not attribute works.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<span class = "darken">
    <span class = "spaceless">
        Test1
    </span>
    Test2
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.darken {
  background: #AAA;
}
.darken:not(.spaceless) {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Output: both Test1 nor Test2 have color: #FFF, and both have background: #AAA.  Why does Test1 have color: #FFF given how it's of class spaceless (which the :not selector should be excluding)?  This doesn't make sense to me.  Even in Fiddle, this code didn't work.  Does anyone have any idea as to why and how I can fix it?  I'd greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.darken:not(.spaceless)` applies to all elements that *do*  have the "darken" class, but, *don't*  have the `.spaceless` class.

To address your `.spaceless` element, the correct selector would be `.darken .spaceless`  (note the space before `.spaceless` to indicate a child element relation.

So `.darken:not(.spaceless)` applies to both texts in your example, and `.darken :not(.spaceless)` applies to none of them - that one would apply to children of `.darken` which *don't*  have the `.spaceless` class.

See also the example below (note also that subsequent rules can overwrite previous ones)

```css
.darken {
  background: #AAA;
}
.darken .spaceless {
    color: green;
}
.darken:not(.spaceless) {
    color: white;
}
.darken :not(.spaceless) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class = "darken">
    <span class = "spaceless">
        Test1
    </span>
    Test2
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment!  This helped me get to the root of the problem.  I replaced my :not(.spaceless) line with .darken:not(.spaceless).darken :(.spaceless) which fixed it.  Marking your answer as correct!

Answer (score 2):

They both have color `#fff` it might be due to your other code they don't but [here is a reference](https://codepen.io/zachiah/pen/XWMQmyo) also

The `:not` selector doesn't work the way you are expecting it to. What

```css
.darken:not(.spaceless)
```

means is it is matching the

```html
<div class="darken">
```

and it won't match

```html
<div class="darken spaceless">
```

so the expected behavior is that they will all have color `#fff` because the `:not()` part of the selector isn't doing anything at all and the inner elements are inheriting the color from the `.darken` element

Comment: Thanks for the comment!  That makes a lot more sense.  In order to achieve what I'm aiming for, what would you recommend?  Is there a way other than by using '>' for me to select elements with both classes indiscriminately of where they are declared?

Comment: No Problem. Can you just add `color: black` to `.spaceless` and `color: white` to `.darken`?

Comment: I got to the bottom of my issue below by adding another condition to the CSS selector, but I appreciate your help!!